# Вывод произвольных типов записи отдельной категории в WP

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть на сайте WP произвольный тип записи Наши работы, сейчас нужно разделить их на 3 части, для этого я добавил Категории для типов записи, но никак не получается вывести записи только одной категории. Пробую выводить таким способом, указывая ярлык категории, но выводятся все равно все, из всех категорий.

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'post_type' => 'completed',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'category' => 'slug'
);
```

UPD. Код полностью

```
    <?php 

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'post_type' => 'completed',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC'       
);

$query_completed = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query_completed->have_posts() ) { 
?>
    <section class="examples-promo">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="examples-promo__title">Выполненные работы</div>
        <div class="examples-promo__list">
        <?php
            while ( $query_completed->have_posts() ) {
                $query_completed->the_post();
                if($compl_imgs_after = get_field('imgs_after',$query_completed->post->ID)[0]['sizes']['large']):
                    $compl_img = ' style="background-image: url('.$compl_imgs_after.')"';
                else:
                    $compl_img = '';
                endif;
            ?>
            <div class="examples-promo__elem">
                <div class="examples-promo__item"<?php echo $compl_img; ?>>
                    <div class="examples-promo__item-inner">
                        <div class="examples-promo__item-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                        <div class="examples-promo__item-hover">
                            <div class="item-hover__title"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn view-project">Смотреть проект</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="more-view-wrap">
            <a href="/completed" class="btn-more btn-more_view">Смотреть больше</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<?php
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

?>

Comment: Для произвольной таксономии используйте tax_query https://codex.wordpress.org/wp_query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: Не получается. Вот у меня есть такой код, он выводит записи произвольного типа "completed", а мне нужно чтобы он выводил только записи с одной категории "slug" 'этого типа, что мне нужно изменить/добавить в нем? Код прикрепил к вопросу.